# Show that the limit exists

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f:[0,1]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ (f continuous)

show that if $x_{m,n}=\frac{m}{n}$, with $m\in\mathbb{N}, n\in\mathbb{Z}_+, 0\leq m \leq n-1$

Then $\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{\sum_{m=0}^{n-1} f(\frac{m}{n})}{n}$ exists.

my teacher showed that the summation is a Cauchy sequence. I tried the same but couldn't really understand it.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Hint: a continuous function on a closed interval is uniformly continuous. Use this to compare the average with $n=n_1$, to the average with $n=n_1n_2$, to the average with $n=n_2$.

Comment: @GregMartin I knew it was uniformly continuous. I'm not seeing this comparison

Answer (score 0):

Well, $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}{\sum_{m=0}^{n-1}f({m\over n})\over n}=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\sum_{m=0}^{n-1}f({m\over n}){1\over n}$. Have you seen this latter expression before? (HINT: think "integration" . . .)

Comment: I didn't notice it at first, but a friend saw the integral definition there, the problem is that we didn't get to the part yet.  Our teacher said that we can't use that to solve the problem.